# Different picker data for every cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have a table view with custom cells, each cell contains a textField. When the user tap on the textfield a UIPickerView will be displayed. I have this approach already done and work good. The thing is, the picker should display different data depending on which textField has been tapped, how can I detect this?

What I've done:

- In viewDidLoad I create a view property which contains a UIPickerView.
- In cellForRowAtIndexPath: I assign that view with the picker as an inputView for the textField (I did it this way to avoid creating a picker everytime a cell is rendered)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution that works really smooth:

- I disabled the textField on every cell
- I stop adding the picker as an inputView in cellForRowAtIndexPath
- Once the user tap on didSelectRowAtIndexPath (which is called when they tap on the textField) I do the following:

if ([dataInfo[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Accessibility"]) {
        pickerItems = accessibilityItems;
    }
    else if ([dataInfo[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Floor"]){
        pickerItems = floorItems;
    }

`[picker reloadAllComponents];


SubCellTableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[cell.subcellSubtitleTextField setEnabled:YES];
cell.subcellSubtitleTextField.inputView = viewContainingPicker;
[cell.subcellSubtitleTextField becomeFirstResponder];`

I hope this can help someone else!